# FireFox hangs with SVG path getTotalLength for some path with two cubic bezier segments

Tags: svg, path

I'm trying to get the total length of the path, but when using getTotalLength() firefox hangs. The same happens for getPointAtLength().
Is there any other way to get the length of the path that wouldn't hang ff ?

http://bl.ocks.org/hnakamur/bc26a6fa7d7b8d9dc795

Comment: Raise a bug in bugzilla. Since you know how to use nightlies, try finding a regression range too.

Comment: This is disappointing, I thought they'd fixed the problems with path length.  See [this bug report for the "fixed" bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984796), but as @RobertLongson said, you'll need to file a new report.  You can probably find references on how to calculate the path yourself, but the math isn't going to be trivial.

Comment: Bug already reported by the author of the example above, almost 2 months ago...